# Importing and exporting breakpoints in visual studio code

Tags: import, export, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Does visual studio code support exporting and importing of breakpoints? If so, how to import and export breakpoints in visual studio code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly?

Comment: I would like to export breakpoints set during a debug session by saving them into a text file and then import them during later debug sessions. I have asked this question on the vscode github forum, apparently it is feature that is still not supported in vscode. Below is the link
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [BreakpointIO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deckerio.breakpointio) extension. Export and import are achieved through JSON files, and instructions can be found in the link provided.

Answer (score 5):

- It appears that there is still not a way to do this. The GitHub issue has been closed - no work appears to have been done there.

  [image: screenshot of GitHub issue]
- I also checked the VS Code extension gallery to search for "breakpoint" / "break point", etc.
- Nada.

Comment: what could be the cause for this, product alignment? to make Visual Studio (NOT VSCode) more competitive at this end of market?